# ASP.NET: Can't update value read from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to edit the values read from the database. My code for read is: (this is found in my page_load)

```
string uname = Session["ApplicantUsername1"].ToString();
txtUsername.Text = uname;

cs.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  NoALastName, NoAFirstName, NoAMiddleName FROM CustomerCreditReport WHERE ApplicantUsername = '" + uname + "'", cs);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    txtLname.Text = reader["NoALastName"].ToString();
    txtFname.Text = reader["NoAFirstName"].ToString();
    txtMname.Text = reader["NoAMiddleName"].ToString();
}
cs.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Now, this is my save/update code. (this is under Save_Click)

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE CustomerCreditReport SET NoALastName = @NoALastName, NoAFirstName = @NoAFirstName, NoAMiddleName = @NoAMiddleName WHERE ApplicantUsername = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'", cs);
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NoALastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLname.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NoAFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFname.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NoAMiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMname.Text;
cs.Open();
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
cs.Close();
```

I am wondering if I have overlooked something. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get any exception?

Comment: Also you are still vulnerable to SQL injection. You should parameterize your `where` clauses too.

Comment: Why do you use a DataAdapter? just use a plain sqlcommand/connection

Comment: Also, instead of while (reader.Read()), you can use if(reader.Read()). As you must be getting only one row from database.

Comment: What your `UpdateCommand` looks like when you add your parameter values? Is it update in your sql server?

Comment: S. Akbari, it doesn't update the values i changed.

Comment: Soner, yes it will update sql server table values, but i doesnt update.

Comment: @Edge Soner asked does your same query works in sql server?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it works in Sql server.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify what your issue is. You have marked an answer as the accepted solution, but it isn't clear what the original issue that has been resolved was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in page load be sure that you put your code after  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
like this

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
  string uname = Session["ApplicantUsername1"].ToString();
        txtUsername.Text = uname;

        cs.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  NoALastName, NoAFirstName, NoAMiddleName FROM CustomerCreditReport WHERE   ApplicantUsername = '" + uname + "'", cs);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtLname.Text = reader["NoALastName"].ToString();
            txtFname.Text = reader["NoAFirstName"].ToString();
            txtMname.Text = reader["NoAMiddleName"].ToString();
        }
        cs.Close();
        reader.Close();
 }
```